# What is meant by the term "factory reset"

Tags: windows

What is meant by the term factory reset? Will my computer come in filled with McAfee bloatware and it's original OS (Windows 8) before upgrade to Windows 10? Just checking before I factory reset this due to BSOD's...

Mostly corrupted expools, system service exceptions and page in nonpage areas. Would be nice to have some tips on how to fix/find out what's causing them then provide more info.

Comment: Factory reset restores your computer to a state in which it came out of the factory or atleast the state in which you got it from the store. So your factory reset will turn your laptop back to Windows 8 + all the bloatware. To fix the bluescreens, you should look for crash dumps located at **c:\windows\minidump\**.

Comment: Alright i'm getting mixed answers...Will my computer turn back into Windows 8 or will i have a "vanilla" install of Windows 10 with nothing but a recycling bin?

Comment: You will get a Windows 8. just use the recovery media that came along with the laptop or those special key combinations that initiate factory reset,  not RESET not REFRESH

Comment: Recovery media? You mean that CD thing you use to install...Alright, brb blowing 70/50 bucks on a new CD....But the thing is i've already got a product ID(unless it's been converted to Windows 10 or can only be used once)...All i need is a clean install of Windows  or something. I didn't get nothing with my laptop except a recycling bin, the thing came pre-installed.

Comment: **be specific**. you want to do a factory reset, you want to do a clean install or you want to fix the blue screen ? make up your mind, edit the post with relevant information & get a good to the point answer.

Comment: Well a factory reset would fix the blue screen, i can't open a dmp let alone understand it... So yeah i probably want to factory reset so it can fix the BSOD's and possibly get Windows 8 back (gonna have to look that up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **What is meant by the term factory reset?**

It depends who is using the term.

If a computer hardware manufacturer such as Dell (or some firmware or software provided by them) uses the term, they mean that it resets the equipment to the state it was when it left the factory, with the same operating system version it had when it left the factory.

If the term is used by the developer of a subsequently installed operating system, it may mean something different - for example a reset to the freshly installed state. Omitting subsequent OS and application updates and installs.

Usually the term implies loss of user data - though this may not always be so.

In short: caveat emptor. Backup important data regularly and check those backups are usable. Make an extra backup before doing anything described as a factory reset.

Comment: So from that if i run Acer eRecovery i will be able to go back to Windows 8 but if i run Reset/Refresh from Settings i will go back to Vanilla 10? is that right?

Comment: Alright i found this video which shows despite the user using Acer eRecovery he/she is booted into Windows Recovery and into the "Resetting" state. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqgYe7OcLhA ... Extra confused.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 you will reset to the basic vanilla install of Windows 10. No bloatware, as that just isn't included with Windows. If you want the bloatware (not that you do) you'd need some install disk from the vendor of your computer.

Of course Windows will not downgrade itself. A reset applies to the current version of Windows you are using.

Comment: Why is it then called factory reset....I don't understand?

Comment: @Tomas Inigo, this information is incorrect

Comment: u guys know how to confuse op ^.^

Comment: No confusing the OP, there is no "factory reset" available in Windows which applies a reset which results in the same setup as an OEM delivers the machine (with bloatware etc)

Reset Windows is just what I explained. There is no way to get the original state of the average laptop, unless by a solution by the OEM.

Answer (score 0):

If you're currently using Windows 10, then performing factory reset will bring you back to the vanilla version of Windows 10, without any additional programs installed.

to all the sceptics, Win10 doesn't use recovery partition: http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/windows-10-will-save-disk-space-and-no-longer-require-recovery-partition

Comment: this is incorrect. Recovery partition has never been touched during OS upgrade

Comment: Windows 10 doesn't use recovery partition: http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/windows-10-will-save-disk-space-and-no-longer-require-recovery-partition

Comment: that does not mean already existing recovery partition cannot be used.